# Pivot table with 2 filters on 1 value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have some data in B3:C7 as follows. I would like to build a pivot table of pairs of Name and Score, such that:

1. we are only interested in the pairs whose score is greater than `2`;
2. we show only the pairs whose score is among Top `1` of the scores.

As a result, only 1 pair (Name: `d`, Score: `4`) should be shown.

G3:H8 was a try that did not satisfy the above conditions. Does anyone know how to customize such a pivot table?
[image]

Comment: Your screenshot has `a` with a score of 1. Please correct screenshot or your question.

Comment: Indeed, I just corrected it.